# Android Login and store cookies to manipulate database

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am new to Android so apolpgies if I am not clear 
I am developing an android application that manipulates a mysql database (phpmyadmin). It has registration and login classes that send the inputs of the textboxes to my JSONPARSER.java class which identifies them as POST methods and sends them to an API on my server which in turn queries the database. This part works, However I want to have it so that when a user is logged in they can add to the database but i need to identify which user is querying the database?

How to I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to have role base identification model in your app. Based on role of user, he can have access. User information can be stored in DB or in shared prefereneces.